# JXDatePicker make arrows in the JXMonthView bigger

Tags: java, user-interface, datepicker

I want to use this JXDatePicker component in a application that will work on a touch display. Because the default component is small, all the dates and the buttons are hard to click using a bad touch screen I wanted to make them bigger. So far I successfully made the result text field bigger (the one showing the selected date, by changing the font), make the pop-up bigger (the JXMonthView, also by changing its font), change the picture of the JXDatePicker with a bigger image, set the default date to be the current date, set the date format, etc. This is my code:

```
private void touch_screen_datepicker(JXDatePicker date_picker) {
        Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        JXMonthView monthView = date_picker.getMonthView();
        date_picker.setDate(new Date());
        date_picker.setFont(new Font(Font.DIALOG, Font.PLAIN, 50));
        JButton btn_pick = (JButton) date_picker.getComponent(1);
        btn_pick.setBackground(new Color(66, 147, 223));
        Image image = toolkit.getImage("/home/adrrian/Image/calendar/" + "calendar image 4.png"); //Земање на сликата за мк знаме
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image); //Правење на икона
        btn_pick.setIcon(icon); //Поставување на иконата
        SimpleDateFormat longFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        SimpleDateFormat shortFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yy-MM-dd");
        Date startDate = new Date(0);//01.01.1970
        shortFormat.set2DigitYearStart(startDate);
        DatePickerFormatter formatter = new DatePickerFormatter(
                // invers sequence for parsing to satisfy the year parsing rules
                new DateFormat[]{shortFormat, longFormat}) {

                    @Override
                    public String valueToString(Object value) throws ParseException {
                        if (value == null) {
                            return null;
                        }
                        return getFormats()[1].format(value);
                    }
                };
        DefaultFormatterFactory factory = new DefaultFormatterFactory(formatter);
        date_picker.getEditor().setFormatterFactory(factory);
        monthView.setFont(new Font(Font.DIALOG, Font.PLAIN, 50));
        monthView.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
    }
```

and this is an image of my final work:
[image]

My main problem is how to make the arrow that are changing the months (for example if I go back from this image to show September). I tried listing all of the components, like I did for the button, but still I didn't found anything. Also for better GUI I like to find that dark blue color (where the month is displayed), to make my button the same.

Hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance.

```
    Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
            JXMonthView monthView = date_picker.getMonthView();
                /*EDITED*/
                //1
                date_picker.putClientProperty("JComponent.sizeVariant", "large");
                monthView.putClientProperty("JComponent.sizeVariant", "large");
                //2
                date_picker.putClientProperty("JXComponent.sizeVariant", "large");
                monthView.putClientProperty("JXComponent.sizeVariant", "large");
                //3
                date_picker.putClientProperty("JXDatePicker.sizeVariant", "large");
                monthView.putClientProperty("JXMonthView.sizeVariant", "large");
                //
                date_picker.putClientProperty("JDatePicker.sizeVariant", "large");
                monthView.putClientProperty("JMonthView.sizeVariant", "large");
                SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(this);
                SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(date_picker);
                SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(monthView);

                date_picker.updateUI();
                monthView.updateUI();
                /*EDITED*/
```

As @Vighanesh Gursale suggested I insterdet this lines and also did the frame.pack() before setVisible(true), but nothing changes.

Comment: You should find the `Look and Feel` defaults of `JXDatePicker`. You can change the size of button by just change the values of default for example use this link. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/size.html

Comment: Sorry but it wont work with it, I set it to large, but nothing happened.

Comment: how you've tried, if you can share it would help you to solve your problem.

Comment: I edited my post and add some code lines, I have tried many combinations of your example and also I did the frame.pack() and after that set visible to true. Also this function touch_screen_datepicker I called in the constructor of the frame.

Answer (score 1):

I have made some code using nimbus look and feel, i know it is not exact that you want but it is pretty much helpful. Check this code. To perform same you need to find the key of your next and previous buttons key in my case it is `Button.margin`. Try to use the same key in your code if you are lucky it would work.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Demo {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
    JButton btn = new JButton("Example");

    public Demo() {
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.add(btn);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try
        {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
            Insets insets = new Insets(50, 20, 50, 20); //change the size of button
            UIManager.put("Button.margin", insets);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Demo d = new Demo();
    }
}
```

Also keep in mind to use default look and feel or any other look and feel.

Comment: I've tried with a regular button and the button from the date picker. To my JButton it changes the margin but on the date picker, wont do a thing. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @AdrianES will let you know if I got any other option or code. But check this link for `JDatePicker` another api which has some features, might be helpful for you. http://sourceforge.net/projects/jdatepicker/

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite old but for everyone who is looking how it can be done

```
UIManager.put("JXMonthView.monthDownFileName", <PATH_TO_IMAGE>);
UIManager.put("JXMonthView.monthUpFileName", <PATH_TO_IMAGE>);
```

monthDownFileName refers to previous month
monthUpFileName refers to next month

this will change the image with other of your choice (and size)